# Qt - Disabling QDialog's "?" button

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I create an instance of QDialog and on the left of 'x' (close) button i have also '?' button. How I can disable that '?' ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Change the window flags, for example in the constructor:

```
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
```

Comment: Trying to call setWindowFlags() directly did not work because the '~' was not applied. Another solution involves using the &= operator:

<pre>
    Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
    flags &= ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint;
    setWindowFlags(flags);
</pre>

Comment: Actually we had the opposite problem, our dialog didn't have Help button.  This answer helped us look for the problem.  Thanks

Comment: And by the way in PySide:  self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)   Does the tilde say to remove that flag?

Comment: Tilde is a bitwise complement operator that flips every bit (0->1, 1->0). & is a bitwise AND operator. When the original bits and flipped flag bits and ANDed, the flag is removed.

Answer (score 5):

From the Qt 4.6 QDialog documentation:

> ```
> QDialog::QDialog ( QWidget * parent  = 0, Qt::WindowFlags  f = 0 )
> ```
>
> Constructs a dialog with parent `parent`.
>
> A dialog is always a top-level widget, but if it has a parent, its default location is centered on top of the parent. It will also share the parent's taskbar entry.
>
> The widget flags `f` are passed on to the `QWidget` constructor. If, for example, **you don't want a **What's This** button in the title bar of the dialog**, pass `Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint` in `f`.

See also [`QWidget::setWindowFlags()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop).

Comment: For QDialog Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint flags cause an abnormal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable the button, you can call `setEnabled(bool)`, but I doubt that's what's being asked.

If you want to remove that button, see below:

`QDialog` is intended to use a `QDialogButtonBox` as the buttons that show up on the dialog.  You can use accessors available in [QDialogButtonBox](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdialogbuttonbox.html) in order to disable the buttons you don't want (as well as enable others).

For example (from the documentation linked to above):

```
findButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Find"));
findButton->setDefault(true);

moreButton = new QPushButton(tr("&More"));
moreButton->setCheckable(true);
moreButton->setAutoDefault(false);

buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(Qt::Vertical);
buttonBox->addButton(findButton, QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);
buttonBox->addButton(moreButton, QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);
```

If you're not aware of the button box, I'd guess that designer automatically added it for you and it should have a name that makes it accessible.  There should also be properties (checkboxes) that you can check in order to control which buttons are accessible by default.

Comment: This is a well-written answer, but I think he was referring to buttons in the title bar for the dialog (window decorations).

Comment: Oh. I think you're right -- I definitely misunderstood that one :(.

Answer (score 0):

For Qt 5.10 and higher you can use application wide flag Qt::AA_DisableWindowContextHelpButton

```
 app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_DisableWindowContextHelpButton);
```