# QDialog: Forbidden Cursor appears when Question Mark (?) Pressed

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to get the 'WhatsThis' functionality working in a QDialog-based application, so when the user clicks the little question mark in the Title Bar, a little 'about' dialog appears.

By default, clicking that button does nothing except change my mouse cursor to the 'Forbidden' cursor:

[image: You have entered the Forbidden Zone!]

Based on [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975534/qdialog-how-to-use-question-mark-to-show-information/26977078#26977078), I reimplemented event as follows:

```
def event(self, event): 
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.EnterWhatsThisMode:
        print "Here is a useful message"
        return True
    return QtGui.QDialog.event(self, event)
```

While this prints out the desired message, I still get the 'Forbidden' cursor, even when I add the following to the above event function:

```
QtGui.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
```

This creates an arrow temporarily, but when I bring the cursor anywhere outside the Title Bar in the app, the cursor turns Forbidden again. It's almost as if it is acting like there is a modal dialog open somewhere that needs to be executed.

How can I stop this Forbidden behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a call to [`QWhatsThis.leaveWhatsThisMode()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwhatsthis.html#leaveWhatsThisMode) in your event handler to exit "What's this?" mode as soon as it's entered.

```
def event(self, event): 
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.EnterWhatsThisMode:
        QtGui.QWhatsThis.leaveWhatsThisMode()
        print "Here is a useful message"
        return True
    return QtGui.QDialog.event(self, event)
```

Comment: Thanks. Very weird...thanks for the link to the docs...I have never seen that class before. Qt seems to have a fractal structure. :)